# Drupal 7 Entity Query Builder Not Giving a return value

Tags: drupal-7

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'exclusion_lists');                 
$entity_type = 'node';
$result = $query->execute();

if (!empty($result[$entity_type])) {
$entities = entity_load($entity_type, array_keys($result[$entity_type]));
}

var_dump($entities->field_first_name);
```

The concept: essentially I take a CSV file, Upload it, Read the contents to an array, get all the first and last names from the exclusion_lists content type, and then scrub it.  I can't seem to get anything out of the $entities variable.  I'm sure it's just sleep deprivation, etc that's getting to me, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you `var_dump($entities)` variable to see the structure of the array. Then probably you need to use `field_get_items` to get the value of the particular field.